# Convert to lower case in Html.DisplayNameFor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

It should be pretty easy, but can't see it...
I have the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new
                        {
                            htmlAttributes = new
                            {
                                @class = "form-control",
                                placeholder = "Please type your " + Html.DisplayNameFor( model => model.FullName),
                                data_bind = "value: product.fullname"
                            }
                        })
```

When I type `Html.DisplayNameFor( model => model.FullName.ToLower())` I get an exception

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access,
>   property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter
>   custom indexer expressions.

How can I manipulate my string inside the `Html.DisplayNameFor`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DisplayFor()` extension method returns an `MvcHtmlString`, so you can convert the return value to a string using `ToString()` and then use `ToLower()`

```
placeholder = "Please type your "
    + Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName).ToString().ToLower()
```